# Rails: How to create a new record in a belongs_to + has_many relationship with both ends validating the presence of each other?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm learning about associations and I'm having trouble creating a new record.

I have a Game model that who's instances must belong_to a manufacturer, so I'm using a presence validation.

Manufactures can have more than one game associated to them so there is a has_many games relationship from the manufacturer's point of view. Also, I want to ensure that a manufacturer is only created if it is associated with a game (through validation) (I don't want to track any manufacturer that does not have any games associated with it).

Here is the code:

```
class Game < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :manufacturer
    validates :name, presence: {message: 'The game name is required'}
    validates :description, presence:  {message: 'A short game descripton is required'}
    validates :manufacturer, presence:  true
 end

class Manufacturer < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :games
    validates :name, presence: {message: 'The manufacurer name is required and must be unique'}
    validates :name, uniqueness: {message: 'A manufactuer by this name already exits.'}, if: "name.present?"
    validates :games, presence: { message: 'Every manufacturer must be associated with at least one game.' }
end
```

So as you can see both validate each other, so there will be no games without manufacturer and no manufacturers without games.

I'm having a hard time trying to create a new record in the db because for creating a game I need to have a manufacturer in the db, but I can't create the manufacturer as it needs to be associated with a game (it's kind of a cycle).

How can I create a new record, given this validation restrictions?
(the DB is properly set up with the columns for foreign keys and ids)

Comment: Can you please explain in your question why the manufacturer MUST have games? I can understand why games MUST belong to a manufacturer but having difficulty understanding the logic for the reverse.

Comment: I already edited the the question.  The reason is that I don't want to track any manufacturer that does not have a game associated with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

can u try something like this?

```
game = Game.new
manufacturer = Manufacturer.new(games: [game])
manufacturer.save
```

and turn on

```
class Manufacturer < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :games, autosave: true
  # etc etc
end
```

Comment: Is this possible without autosave?

Comment: Yes it is possible to remove autosave. however one will have to call game.save manually afterwards.

Comment: I tried it without the autosave and manufacturer.save saves both, the manufacturer and the game, any idea why?

Comment: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/AutosaveAssociation.html
According to rails reference, autosave: true save all children. If autosave is absent, one new children records are saved.